# Pure Javascript display won't make things invisible

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a row in a table invisible using pure Javascript on page load. My code looks something like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     window.onload = function () {
         document.getElementById("AmzDivSettings1").style.display = 'none';
     }</script>
```

and later

```
<tr id="AmzDivSettings1"> ... </tr>
```

Its not working, can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Works just fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/YjwyH/1/ *<--updated to reflect updated question.*

Comment: have you tried it with another tag, than `td`?! maybe the table-structure avoids to hide the element

Answer (score 1):

You want to hide the row element [tr], not the cell [td].